# Xcode code completion custom descriptions

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

For some methods, Xcode's code completion / suggestion / auto-complete feature displays descriptions:

[image: description shown in code completion]

When I create classes, functions, variables, and what not and do provide descriptions, the description does not show up:

[image: description of custom function **not** showing]

However, in the quick help menu on the right hand side, and when clicking `alt+click`, it does:

[image: description in quick menu works]

I tried [this "solution"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41502785/3397217), but it did not work. Is there any special characters I need to include in the description?

#### Note

I am currently on Xcode 9 beta 1, but I also experienced this issue in Xcode 8.

#### Update

Glad to say that it now works for me in Xcode 9 GM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason might be that there is no space after **///**.
Right way should be

```
/// This is a description
```

As a matter of fact, if you add documentation for a function as mentioned in screenshot, comments are itself added wherein you can see that space is there after ///. Which is intact the right way to add comments/documentation.
Once you option click on the function calling, description is displayed.
The way Apple displays the description in autocomplete is something it does by itself. You may want to use [**AppleDoc**](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc) for this.

[image]

Comment: Uhh for me that does not seem to work. I also hit `shift+cmd+k` to clean, but it still does not appear.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth : Edited my answer. Can you check again.

Comment: You might have misunderstood my question: I'm not looking for the description to appear when option clicking - that already works. I want the description to show up when hitting `esc` to have the code suggestions pop up. (And whenever else the suggestions appear.)

Comment: @LinusGeffarth : Correct. And that is why I have suggested AppleDoc in my answer :) That should solve your issue.

Comment: Oh, right. If possible, I'd like to not use third party software… Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

### Objective-C

**1. Just add description before your method just like example.**

```
@interface VVLabelBold : UILabel
-(void) setDefaultTextColor;

/**Disabled Label, This description will show in auto-complete*/
-(void) setDisabled;

@end
```

**2 Call Method for UILabel**

```
[lblSample setDisabled];
```

[image: #]